# access response in SOAP UI in Groovy Script

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am new to Groovy Scripting. I am trying to access the value of a Response node
below is the script

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context);
def responseHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( testRunner.testCase.testSteps["request"].testRequest.response.responseContent );
responseHolder.namespaces["ns0"]="http://xmlns.int.com/orders/xsd/v1"
String mySection = responseHolder.getNodeValue["//ns0:MT_OrderCreateDTCFulfillmentResponse/ns0:StatusCode"] ;
log.info mySection
```

mySection is printed as []

Response XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header xmlns:v1="http://xmlns.int.com/orders/xsd/v1"/>
   <soapenv:Body xmlns:v1="http://xmlns.int.com/orders/xsd/v1">
      <ns0:MT_OrderCreateDTCFulfillmentResponse xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.int.com/orders/xsd/v1">
         <StatusCode>000</StatusCode>
         <ReferenceDocNbr>NA</ReferenceDocNbr>
         <SchemaValidationStatus>Validated</SchemaValidationStatus>
         <StatusTimestamp>2015-08-03T18:58:01.602</StatusTimestamp>
         <FaultDetails>Request for customer order number NA received successfully and format validated.</FaultDetails>
      </ns0:MT_OrderCreateDTCFulfillmentResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

SOAP UI Project Structure - I am running Test_Script. Suggest me what i am missing
[image: SOAP UI Project structue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to use:

`responseHolder.getNodeValue("//ns0:MT_OrderCreateDTCFulfillmentResponse/StatusCode");`

instead of `responseHolder.getNodeValue["//ns0:MT_OrderCreateDTCFulfillmentResponse/ns0:StatusCode"];`

Note that I change `responseHolder.getNodeValue` invocation to use `()` instead of `[]`, and also change your `xpath` since in your response `<StatusCode>` it's not defined in `xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.int.com/orders/xsd/v1"`.

Another option is to use the `*` wildcard as a namespace to map anyone. So in this case you can use:

`responseHolder.getNodeValue("//*:MT_OrderCreateDTCFulfillmentResponse/*:StatusCode");`

Additionally, note that probably you XML is wrong, since I suppose that all sub elements of `<MT_OrderCreateDTCFulfillmentResponse>` must belongs to `"http://xmlns.int.com/orders/xsd/v1"` namespace... so you've to declare it as:

```
<ns0:MT_OrderCreateDTCFulfillmentResponse xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.int.com/orders/xsd/v1">
         <ns0:StatusCode>000</ns0:StatusCode>
         <ns0:ReferenceDocNbr>NA</ns0:ReferenceDocNbr>
         <ns0:SchemaValidationStatus>Validated</ns0:SchemaValidationStatus>
         <ns0:StatusTimestamp>2015-08-03T18:58:01.602</ns0:StatusTimestamp>
         <ns0:FaultDetails>Request for customer order number NA received successfully and format validated.</ns0:FaultDetails>
      </ns0:MT_OrderCreateDTCFulfillmentResponse>
```

Or using as default for this tag:

```
<MT_OrderCreateDTCFulfillmentResponse xmlns="http://xmlns.int.com/orders/xsd/v1">
         <StatusCode>000</StatusCode>
         <ReferenceDocNbr>NA</ReferenceDocNbr>
         <SchemaValidationStatus>Validated</SchemaValidationStatus>
         <StatusTimestamp>2015-08-03T18:58:01.602</StatusTimestamp>
         <FaultDetails>Request for customer order number NA received successfully and format validated.</FaultDetails>
      </MT_OrderCreateDTCFulfillmentResponse>
```

Note that if you change you XML with my indication your first XPath it's correct since now `StatusCode` belongs to your namespace.

Hope it helps,

Comment: @VamsiKrishna you're welcome `:)`, nice to help you.